# Whenever I want to type "A, the text is converted to Ä

Tags: internationalization, language

Whenever I want to type "A, the text is converted to Ä

For example, I want to type the following text:

```
"A wonderful letter"
```

When I start typing, I get this:

```
Ä wonderful letter"
```

How to fix the issue with the `Ä` letter appearing instead of `"A`?

Comment: Check the Input Sources in Keyboard System Preferences to make sure that right keyboard type is selected. Also check under Text to rule out any replacement text set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To diagnose and resolve the issue, verify the input configuration by going to System Preferences app → Keyboard and verifying the following:

1. Click on **Input Sources** tab and make sure there is only one item on the list, either US or ABC (and NOT US International PC, which behaves the way you describe on purpose to facilitate making accented characters).
2. Click on **Text** tab and verify no undesired text replacement are configured. If present, remove it.

Answer (score 3):

I had "US International" keyboard selected. After replacing it with "US", the problem disappeared.

Comment: You should give credit to @NimeshNeema by accepting his answer!

Comment: @IconDaemon if you look at the timestamps, you'll see that this answer is the oldest.

Comment: First, he suggested the same idea in the comments.